# Angularjs Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.$current.locals[l]')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, angular-ui-router

I have an angular project set up that when a user goes to `/cloud` and they aren't logged in (`isLoggedIn()` return fails), it redirect to `/login`. And then if they are logged in and go to `/login` it redirects them back to `/cloud`.

However, when I click the logout button to clear the local storage, I get the following error (everything still works):

> Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.$current.locals[l]')

According to my logs, it appears to be happening on the `onEnter` for my logout controller.

I'm new to angular so any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
var routerApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router'])
    //config for state changes
    .factory('Auth', function($http, $state, $q) {

        var factory = { isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn };
        return factory;

        function isLoggedIn(token) {
            return $http.post('/auth/session', {token:token});
        }

    })
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cloud');

        var authenticated = ['$q', 'Auth', '$rootScope', function ($q, Auth, $rootScope) { 
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (typeof window.localStorage['authtoken'] === 'undefined') {
                var authtoken = undefined;
            } else {
                var authtoken = window.localStorage['authtoken'];
            }
            Auth.isLoggedIn(authtoken).then(function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            }, function() {
                deferred.reject();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }];

        var authGuest = ['$q', 'Auth', '$rootScope', function ($q, Auth, $rootScope) { 
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (typeof window.localStorage['authtoken'] === 'undefined') {
                var authtoken = undefined;
            } else {
                var authtoken = window.localStorage['authtoken'];
            }
            Auth.isLoggedIn(authtoken).then(function() {
                deferred.reject();
            }, function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }];

        $stateProvider

            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'pages/templates/login.html',
                resolve: { authenticated: authGuest }
            })

            .state('logout', { url: '/logout', onEnter: function($state) { localStorage.clear(); $state.go('login'); } })

            .state('cloud', {
                url: '/cloud',
                templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html',
                resolve: { authenticated: authenticated }
            })

    })
    .run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, from, error) {
            if(from.name == "login") {
                $state.go('cloud');
            } else {
                $state.go('login');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1833 and https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1901

Comment: Try onEnter: function($state,$window) { $window.localStorage.clear(); $state.go('login'); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
    var authenticated = ['$q', 'Auth', '$rootScope', function ($q, Auth, $rootScope) { 
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (typeof window.localStorage['authtoken'] === 'undefined') {
            var authtoken = undefined;
        } else {
            var authtoken = window.localStorage['authtoken'];
        }
        Auth.isLoggedIn(authtoken).then(function() {
            deferred.resolve();
        }, function() {
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }];
```

This function will only run once on ***`Configuration`***. The promise, once resolved, will continue to resolve to same value regardless of `LocalStorage`. Every time you

```
resolve: { authenticated: authenticated }
```

You will get back the `authenticated` value at ***`Configuration`*** step.

instead, add a controller to define functions to request status for each type

```
  .controller('AuthenticationController', function($scope, '$q', Auth, '$rootScope') {
        $scope.authenticated = function () { 
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (typeof window.localStorage['authtoken'] === 'undefined') {
                var authtoken = undefined;
            } else {
                var authtoken = window.localStorage['authtoken'];
            }
            Auth.isLoggedIn(authtoken).then(function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            }, function() {
                deferred.reject();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        $scope.authGuest = function ($scope, '$q', Auth, '$rootScope') { 
            ....
            return deferred.promise;
        };

    });
```

Then, in your routing configurations:

```
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/login.html',
            controller: 'AuthenticationController'
            resolve: { authenticated: $scope.authGuest() }
        })
        .state('cloud', {
            url: '/cloud',
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html',
            resolve: { authenticated: $scope.authenticated()}
        })
```

Now, each time you be resolving a fresh promise.

**Disclaimer:** Without a working version to use, I formed this code for demonstration purposes. It should be treated a pseudo-code to lead in right direction.